# iOS: reachability and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2, reachability

I have this code in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{



    [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

        if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable){
            NSLog(@"NO CONNECTION");
        }
        else if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN){

            NSLog(@"YES CONNECTION");
        }
    }];

[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];

return YES;
}
```

but it don't work, I have not my logs, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block is only called when the reachability actually changes.

You can get the current status like this:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] reachable]
```

Comment: in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' it don't work and it work at example in 'didBecomeActive'

Comment: Well, if it works in `didBecomeActive`, why bother using it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: ok, but if it work fine in didBecomeActive, what's the way to get the reachability to other classes?

Comment: You could create a class method, to query the reachability and create a delegate to notify every class you need about changing reachability.

Comment: and I should call how many time? everytime I enter in my view? at example in 'viewWillAppear'?

Comment: or do you mean with 'NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter'?

Comment: Depends on how you want to do it and how you need it.